# Reading the serial number of USB storage device in Vb

Tags: vb.net, usb

Is it possible to read the serial number of a USB drive using VB.

Answer (score 1):

this will give you the info on your drives in .net, including usb devices
Just import these

Imports Scripting
Imports System.IO

```
Private Class USBsn
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
       Dim driveNames As New List(Of String)
       For Each drive As DriveInfo In My.Computer.FileSystem.Drives
          Try
            Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
            Dim oDrive As Drive

            fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

            oDrive = fso.GetDrive(drive.Name)

            ListBox1.Items.Add(drive.Name & "   " & oDrive.SerialNumber)
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Google found these tutorials:

visual basic (for hdd serial, but it seems it works for a usb drive too):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/hard_disk_serialno.aspx

powershell and vbasic:

http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2007/02/24/displaying-usb-devices-using-wmi.aspx

vbasic:

http://www.myitforum.com/forums/m_147418/mpage_1/key_/tm.htm

Answer (score 0):

It's in the registry, `HKLM\System\CCS\Enum\USB\VID_XXXX&PID_YYYY\<serial>`.
(Vendor and Product ID will vary too, as serial numbers are only unique for a single product.)