# Reading from and writing to files on a USB drive

Tags: vb.net

I know how to save and load files to a set path, but this needs to load from and save to a USB drive. I obviously can’t set it to `E:\` or anything, as the letter varies by computer. How can I get the right path?

Comment: You can use the `DriveInfo` class to look at what drives exist.

Comment: You will be using a specific USB drive?
In that case you can loo through your drives and read the serial number of each and the one matching your drives serial will be the drive you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you need to detect insertion of a drive first, then you can get the drive letter of it.

see this article: [How to detect insertion and removal of other USB Peripherals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779475/how-to-detect-insertion-and-removal-of-other-usb-peripherals)

Answer (score 0):

Use `DriveInfo.GetDrives` Method to retrieves the drive names of all logical drives on a computer.

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO

Class Test
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim allDrives() As DriveInfo = DriveInfo.GetDrives()

        Dim d As DriveInfo
        For Each d In allDrives
            Console.WriteLine("Drive {0}", d.Name)
            Console.WriteLine("  File type: {0}", d.DriveType)
        Next 
    End Sub 
End Class
```

see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158427/reading-the-serial-number-of-usb-storage-device-in-vb) sample to find your drives and read the serial of each and match against your device serial. Thus the drive which matches your serial can be used to read/write files.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Make a combo box and a text boxes on your form.

You can use the combo box to select a removable device if there are more than 1.
"the 1e one will be automatically selected"

The text box will just show you the drive letter of the selected drive.

I used a button to test the code!

So in the for each , check if the drive is ready and if its a removable drive.
"If RemovableDrived.IsReady = True AndAlso RemovableDrived.DriveType = IO.DriveType.Removable Then"
If true add it to the combo box.
So your combo box will have all the removable drives in it.

If you know the usb device name and and you want to look for that, you could add this in the for each just before you add the items to the combo box
"If RemovableDrived.VolumeLabel = "RemovableDriveName" Then"

You can use ResultDrive for your drive letter. " It will show the selected drive root"
So in the combo box SelectedIndexChanged event I give ResultDrive his value.

Last thing ! 
Because you didn't provide much code and info i Give you the drive letter of the removable drives.
" Else you need to provide more info on how you want to select the drive and if it will have the same name always and so on "

If you need more help on this , let me know :)"

```
Dim AllDrives() As IO.DriveInfo = IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives()
Dim ResultDrive As String

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ComboBox1.Items.Clear()

    For Each RemovableDrive In AllDrives
        If RemovableDrive.IsReady = True AndAlso RemovableDrive.DriveType = IO.DriveType.Removable Then
           'If RemovableDrive.VolumeLabel = "RemovableDriveName" Then
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(RemovableDrive.RootDirectory).ToString()
           'End If
        End If
    Next
    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    ResultDrive = Convert.ToString(ComboBox1.SelectedItem)
    TextBox1.Text = ResultDrive
End Sub
```